# Update Configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I need to update a configurable product but when I go to product and "create configuration" I read  this

> When you remove or add an attribute, we automatically update all
>   configurations and you will need to recreate current configurations
>   manually.

Is there a way to add configurable product without deleting those already created?

[image]